# filtet data by checkbox using jquery ajax mysql and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, checkbox

I have a group of dynamic checkbox of location

```
<?php foreach($qry_2 as $v2) { ?>
    <li class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="i-check" id="locality" name="locality[]" value="<?php echo $v2['outlet_locality'] ?>"><?php echo $v2['outlet_locality'] ?>
            <small class="location"><?php echo '('.$v2['outletCount'].')' ?></small>
        </label>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

and I got aprox 10 input checkbox values
I want to filter the content according to the checkbox(multiple select) using jQuery and send data to `filter.php` to retrive as json data

```
$('input#locality').change(function () {
    var locality = [];
    $(':checkbox:checked').each(function (i) {
        locality.push($(this).val());
    });

    $.post("php/filter.php", {name: locality}, function(data){

    });
});
```

when I checked the checkbox I got indivisual value not an array, so how can I get the array value of multiple checkbox checked to send to and retrive data from `filter.php`
my filter.php

```
$qry_1 = array();

$checkbox1 = $_POST['name'];  
$chk = "";   
foreach($checkbox1 as $chk1)  
{  
    $chk .= $chk1.",";  
}
$sql_1 = "SELECT  p.id,p.outlet_id,p.offer_title,p.original_price,p.discount,p.discount_price,p.offer_image,p.offer_details,o.outlet_id,o.outlet_title,o.outlet_locality,o.segment_type FROM products as p,outlets as o WHERE p.outlet_id=o.outlet_id AND o.outlet_locality='$chk'"; 
$qry_1 = sel_qry($sql_1);
foreach($qry_1 as $v)
{
    $filterloc[] = array('title'=>$v['outlet_title'],'cat_id'=>$v['outlet_id']);
}
echo json_encode($filterloc);
```

i am getting null value do guide me

Comment: Avoid reference to html elements in loop by using unique id in jquery/javascript. In your case its ``id="locality". Either generate these ids dynamically or better use a class. If you make this change then it might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving this

```
$.post("filter.php", { name: locality[i] }, function (data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

to outside of the each. i.e:

```
$('input#locality').change(function () {
  var locality = [];
  $(':checkbox:checked').each(function (i) {
    locality.push($(this).val());
    alert(locality[i])
  });

  $.post("filter.php", { name: locality }, function (data) {
    alert(data);
  });
});
```

(Assuming your backend expects an array, of course)

Comment: it send name[]:location1  name[]:location2 then how can i get this value in my filter.php @geo1302

Comment: $qry_1=array();

 $checkbox1=$_POST['name'];  
$chk="";   
foreach($checkbox1 as $chk1)  
   {  
      $chk .= $chk1.",";  
   }
$sql_1="SELECT  p.id,p.outlet_id,p.offer_title,p.original_price,p.discount,p.discount_price,p.offer_image,p.offer_details,o.outlet_id,o.outlet_title,o.outlet_locality,o.segment_type FROM products as p,outlets as o WHERE p.outlet_id=o.outlet_id AND o.outlet_locality='$chk'"; 
$qry_1=sel_qry($sql_1);
foreach($qry_1 as $v)
{
 $filterloc[]=array('title'=>$v['outlet_title'],'cat_id'=>$v['outlet_id']);
}
echo json_encode($filterloc);   i got null value do guide me @geo1302

Comment: Sorry, my knowledge of PHP is close to none. I helped out in the Javascript part, but from a little search you can access the array like so: <? $myArray = $_REQUEST['name']; ?>

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

**HTML**

```
<li class="checkbox">
   <label>
       <input type="checkbox" class="i-check" id="locality" name="locality[]" value="<?php echo $v2['outlet_locality'] ?>"><?php echo $v2['outlet_locality'] ?>
       <small class="location"><?php echo '('.$v2['outletCount'].')' ?></small>
   </label>
</li>
```

**JS**

```
$('input.i-check').change(function () {
    var locality = [];
      $(':checkbox:checked').each(function (i) {
            locality.push($(this).val());
      });

      $.post("jquery1.php", {name: locality}, function(data){

      });
});
```

Instead of id `locality`, used class `i-check`